# Symfony 4 How to add an attribute to a twig using jquery?

Tags: twig, symfony4

I'm trying to do a form with symfony 4. It works fine. But I have a problem.
I have a field to write a comment. By default, it's not required. 
However, I would like to change this using jquery.
This is what I tried to do.

Here, it's my twig:

```
 <div class="information" id="informationForm">

        {{ form_row(recordForm.category) }}
        {{ form_row(recordForm.information) }}


        {{ form_label(recordForm.comment) }}
        {{ form_widget(recordForm.comment, {'attr': {'class': 'comment'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(recordForm.comment) }}

        <button id="add_information_button" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter un renseignement</button>
        <button id="count_div" class="btn btn-primary">Compter</button>
        <button class="remove_information_button btn btn-primary">Supprimer un renseignement</button>

    </div>
```

Here it's the javascript:

```
   $('.information')
    .on("change", ".record_to_information_form_information", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $commentState = $(this).find('option:selected').data('comment')

        //Test: to know if i received the attribute
        console.log($commentState)

        if($commentState===false){
            //the field isn't required
           // {{ form_widget(recordForm.comment, {'attr': {'required': 'false'}}) }}
        }else{
            //the field is required
            // {{ form_widget(recordForm.comment, {'attr': {'required': 'true'}}) }}
        }

    })
;
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can toggle required property value from your jQuery code.

I assume that `data-comment` attribute has type boolean and it's always set, so your toggle statement can look as follows:

```
$('.information')
    .on("change", ".record_to_information_form_information", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $commentState = $(this).find('option:selected').data('comment');

        //Test: to know if i received the attribute
        console.log($commentState);

        $('.comment').prop('required', $commentState);
    });
```

If you need to do something else in your if-else statement, you can just leave your condition as you provided in sample:

```
if ($commentState === false) {
    //the field isn't required
    $('.comment').prop('required', false);
} else {
    //the field is required
    $('.comment').prop('required', true);
}
```